# Copyright notices: What if I change my surname? What if someone else has the exact same name?

Tags: licensing, copyright

I'm adding copyright notices to all my source code files:

```
Copyright (C) 2013 My-First-Name My-Surname
```

1. But what if someone else is also named *My-First-Name My-Surname*? What does courts think about that? How would they know who is the real author? Is there something I can/should do about this situation? (So they'd know for sure)
2. What if I change my surname. Then, how do other people know that I'm still the copyright holder? Is there something I can/should do, to avoid trouble with copyright, after I've changed my name?

**An example** of when the above could be of interest: Someone gets married and change his/her surname and moves to a new address. Then, even if s/he has submitted his/her source code to the U.S. Copyright Office, that was done using his/her old name and address. Now s/he however has a new name and address. But there is perhaps other people that have the old name (but not also the old address). (In my country, for any first + middle + surname, there are usually many people with that full name.)

Apparently people think this is a weird question, but I've read about rather many very decisions made in courts, e.g. someone suing for hot coffee and winning millions of dollars.

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't a programming question, it's a legal question, as well as being a hypothetical. Courts (generally) aren't stupid. If there was a dispute over which person with the same name was the copyright holder they'd require evidence of authorship.

Comment: Voting to close, but with a suggestion: get a domain name. That will be unique. You don't need to add hosting etc. if you don't want to.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant and MarjanVenema: Does there happen to be another StackExchange site that's more appropriate? I had the impression that licensing & copyright questions were okay at Programmers.

Comment: CharlesE.Grant and @MarjanVenema: Okay, so if I have access to the relevant Git repo, and to the related domain name, I suppose that would resolve any conflicts with anyone else with the same name. And I get the feeling that "(born 1979)" really isn't needed. Thanks

Comment: @KajMagnus: Here we go AGAIN.  In the United States of America, in a copyright dispute, the person with the earliest-dated copyright registration certificate wins.  In practical terms, in the US, if you don't register your copyright, you WILL NOT WIN the court case, mainly because the scumbag who stole your stuff will register it in HIS name, figuring (correctly, most of the time) that you're an idiot who is too stupid or too lazy to take the simplest, most effective first step there is to protect your copyright.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm The reason I asked this question is actually that I had started adding copyright notices & license notices, to prepare my code for sending it to the U.S. Copyright Office. And I started wondering about what happens if there are other people with the same name as the one in my copyright notice (and the one used in the U.S. Copyright Office filing).

Comment: @KajMagnus: When and if you have to go to court to defend your copyright, you will be asked to produce your copyright registration certificate.  Your possession of the certificate establishes your ownership of the copyrighted material.  The Bad Guy may have the same name as you, but he won't have physical possession of your copyright registration certificate, ergo, he won't be able to produce it in court.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copyright notices are optional in any country that is part of the Berne Convention (*e.g.*, the USA).  You have a copyright in everything you write, even if you don't include a notice.  Adding a notice increases the legal risk to someone who violates your copyright.  If you really want to hit them with a big stick, you don't just include a notice, but also register your copyright (in the USA, with the US Copyright Office), then any damages you get to claim increase significantly.

The whole point is to put others on notice that you own the code.  It is **not** to **establish** your ownership.

Comment: Berne Convention notwithstanding, if you ever have to go to court in the USA to defend your copyright against a scumbag, you *will* need that copyright registration certificate.  At best, your case will be thrown out if you don't have the certificate.  At worst, the scumbag will have filed for registration, HE will show up with a certificate, and YOU *WILL* LOSE YOUR CASE unless you can produce a copyright registration certificate that predates his.  I am aware of the provisions of the Berne Convention: I am telling you about the reality on the ground.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: And another case where US litigation system has gone haywire and has lost its ability to protect and defend those in the right against those willing to abuse it for their own gain.